# Desktop missing after update of graphics driver

Tags: graphics

I get a blank screen on boot since updating my graphics driver. The wireless indicator is on and working but the other elements of the desktop are missing and I can't do anything. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

My system is HP Pavillion dm4
Processor: Intel (R) Core (TM) i3-2310M CPU 2.10GHz

Comment: I have tried running Terminal ctrl+alt+T, f1, f7, f8, none of them is taking me to terminal

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like the GPU and the driver? Can you log in before it goes blank? More details are always better than fewer.

Comment: Graphics driver is intel. no options for login in. it usually boots straight to desktop

Comment: See section 3: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078

Comment: I have followed the thread you sent and tried the options there but not avail.

Answer (score 2):

I finally get it to work by reinstalling the `ubuntu-desktop` package. Here is what i did:

1. Booted into recovery mode with the most recent kernel (something like `Ubuntu with Linux 3.2.0-25-generic-pae (recovery mode)`)
2. After the recovery mode has finished loading the recovery options, I chose to boot with networking on and then selected `Drop to root shell prompt`
3. I entered the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   ```
4. I rebooted

And bingo that did it. Thanks to [this article too](http://jiakaizhang.com/fix-frozen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have another machine connected to the same network, try to connect to the machine, check the logs `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. You might need to change the graphics the acceleration to `SNA/EXA/UXA`. Unfortunatelly, I can't give you a valid config file, because my HDD died a few days ago.

Comment: Thanks for your response Pavol, unfortunately i dont know how to work with ubuntu sharing system so i  dont know how to access the machine from another machine. Is there something else  i could do? Thanks

Comment: Try ssh from terminal. `ssh login@server` and post me the output of cat `/var/log/Xorg.0.conf`

Comment: ssh login@server

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname server: Name or service not known. while /vat/log/Xorg... replies No such file or directory

Comment: `/var` :) Maybe you haven't installed it yet.

Comment: how do i install it? also not that i have been using the system and it works well until the update i did.

Comment: You install it by typing `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

Comment: Thanks Pavol. if i install this will it solve the issue or just to get at something else?

Comment: This helped me solve the issue: http://jiakaizhang.com/fix-frozen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04/#comment-2503